# PHP Parent Class is a DB connection: Will multiple use due to inheritance affect performance?

Tags: php

I have a class that handles connections:

```
Class db_connect{

    private $server;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $database;

    protected function Connect(){
        $this->server = "localhost";
        $this->username = "root";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->database = "db_test";

        $conn = new mysqli($this->server, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

If I have a couple of child class that extends to this parent, will it affect the performance somehow since it is always trying to connect several times?
If so how can I possibly improve on it? Thanks.

Comment: I´d rather have a `setDatabaseConnection(db_connect $dbConnection)` and set it, so you´d only have one instance/connection.

Comment: https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php 'Practical example::database class' part if you don't need to change in runtime the connection always

Comment: That way you will end up creating multiple connection. Multiply that by multiple users and soon you will exceed the MySQL connection limit

Comment: @golddragon007 thanks for this useful info. you hit the spot.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt Thanks for this, I'll try it too :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I suspected. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll connect every time you invoke that method. However, let's rewrite it a bit:

```
Class db_connect{

    private $server;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private static $connection;

    protected function Connect() {      
        if(!(static::$connection instanceof mysqli)) {
            $this->server = "localhost";
            $this->username = "root";
            $this->password = "";
            $this->database = "db_test";

            static::$connection = new mysqli($this->server, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
        }

        return static::$connection;
    }
}
```

In the above example, there's only one connection, ever. That's why it's defined as `static`. Now you can call `$obj->Connect();` as many times as you want, it'll be using one connection only. Others mentioned it, it's called a singleton. There are drawbacks and advantages to it, but that's outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: Hi Mjh, thanks so much! I was going to learn this Singleton stuff then it blew my mind luckily you already wrote it for me :) I have this one problem, I used your code and i tested it with a child class named My_Class with a method called My_Method, I called My_Method, but then an error occured: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access property My_Class::$connection. What could this mean?

Comment: never mind. I figured out the problem. I just changed private static $connection to protected. Again, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @AdrianCelis no problem, I'm glad you got it sorted out, best of luck with php! :)